# Bootstrap and oembed conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, oembed

My problem is with the jquery.js file which gets added along with Bootstrap.

When jquery.js is active I cannot open videos, E.G: oembed video does not work. But when I remove jquery.js, oembed video works perfectly.

jquery.js is important in my design (based on Bootstrap) so I cannot just remove it.

Any ideas on how to go about solving this issue?

I use jquery.min and jquery.oembed for oembed, but on the same page I must to disable jQuery which is a part of Bootstrap js folder.

How to make jQuery and oembed work on the same page, that is the problem. 
I have mentioned that jQuery is important for dropdown menu, modal etc.., included into my web design.

Comment: Try put your source code, or better a JSFiddle please ?

Comment: Are you including jQuery with oembed?

Comment: yes I need jquery for my design is a part of bootstrap js folder but I must to disable jquery (I just remove s from js) if I want video to show up on that video page stupid solution on other pages I use jquery for dropdown modal etc..